# Wordpress creating a compund query or using data from one post type to access another

Tags: php

I have created two post types, events and registrations and would like to be able to loop through the events and then fetch the registrations for each event, but WP_Query seems not to be working.

The data is setup for 9 events and 3 registrations, two for one event and one for another

It seems to not fetch the registration data correctly.

```
            $events = new WP_Query(Array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_type' => 'event'
            ));
            if ($events->have_Posts()){
                while($events->have_posts()){
                    $events->the_post();
                    echo "<p>Event " . get_the_title() . '</p>';
                    $eventID = $events->get_the_ID();
                    echo $eventID;
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'registration',
                        'meta_key' => 'event_id',
                        'meta_value' => $eventID,
                        'meta_compare' => '='
                    );

                    $registrations = new WP_Query($args);
                    while ($registrations->have_posts()){
                        $registrations->the_post();
                        echo "<p>The registrations list "  . get_the_title() . "</p>";
                    }
                }
            }
```

I get the following results

```
Event 1
Event 2
Event 3
Event 4
Event 5
Event 6
Event 7
Event 8
Event 9
```

If I change the line `'meta_compare' => '='`  to `'meta_compare' => '!='`
I get the following

```
Event 1
The registrations list for Evnt 1
The registrations list for Evnt 2
The registrations list for Evnt 1
Event 2
The registrations list for Evnt 1
The registrations list for Evnt 2
The registrations list for Evnt 1
Event 3
The registrations list for Evnt 1
The registrations list for Evnt 2
The registrations list for Evnt 1
Event 4
The registrations list for Evnt 1
The registrations list for Evnt 2
The registrations list for Evnt 1
Event 5
The registrations list for Evnt 1
The registrations list for Evnt 2
The registrations list for Evnt 1
Event 6r Registration
The registrations list for Evnt 1
The registrations list for Evnt 2
The registrations list for Evnt 1
Event 7
The registrations list for Evnt 1
The registrations list for Evnt 2
The registrations list for Evnt 1
Event 8
The registrations list for Evnt 1
The registrations list for Evnt 2
The registrations list for Evnt 1
Event 9
The registrations list for Evnt 1
The registrations list for Evnt 2
The registrations list for Evnt 1
```

Not sure why this is proving to be so hard, maybe it's because they're both posts, just different types, from the same table.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [WP documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query),

> **Using the WP_Meta_Query::parse_query_vars( $query ) method**: You can
>   use this method, if you want to use the simple query args(`meta_key`,
>   `meta_value`, `meta_type`, `meta_compare`), or if you are unsure of
>   the presence of meta query parameters.

Hence, I tried converting `meta_key`, `meta_value` and `meta_compare` in source code to wrap inside `meta_query` as `key`, `value`, `compare`.

Also, added `if( $registrations->have_post() ) {`

Can you check if below code snippet works for you ?

```
            $events = new WP_Query(Array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_type' => 'event'
            ));
            if ($events->have_posts()){
                while($events->have_posts()){
                    $events->the_post();
                    echo "<p>Event " . get_the_title() . '</p>';
                    $eventID = $events->get_the_ID();
                    echo $eventID;
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'registration',
                        'meta_query' => array (
                          'key' => 'event_id',
                          'value' => $eventID,
                          'compare' => '='
                        )
                    );

                    $registrations = new WP_Query($args);
                    if( $registrations->have_post() ) { 
                      while ($registrations->have_posts()){
                        $registrations->the_post();
                        echo "<p>The registrations list "  . get_the_title() . "</p>";
                      }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Edit 1 :

If the `event_id` is an ACF then you should try fetching registrations using ACF functions.

Ref: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/

```
echo $eventID;
$registrations = get_posts(array(
   'numberposts'   => -1,
   'post_type'     => 'registration',
   'meta_query'    => array(
       array(
           'key'       => 'event_id',
           'value'     => $eventID,
           'compare'   => '=',
       ),
   ),
));

if( $registrations->have_post() ) { 
 while ($registrations->have_posts()){
   $registrations->the_post();
   echo "<p>The registrations list "  . get_the_title() . "</p>";
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry this didn't work.I think it revolves around the met_query in the $args. It's not selecting the $registrations rows correctly. In the registrations table there is a "ACF" custom field called "event_id". This holds the ID of the parent event. As it is a "relationship" field I wonder if there are any issues there with the search as with '=' I get nothing but with '!=' I get 3 every time. Are there special considerations when using IDs or numerics in searches.

Comment: If the `event_id` is an ACF then you should try fetching registrations using ACF functions.

Ref: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/

@PeterB : Added "Edit 1" to my answer with code snippet for ACF.

See if this works.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to sort this with your help, thanks. I have still used WP_Query but the problem lay in the fact that the event_id is a relationship and therefore an array, so "=" as the meta_type wouldn't work
Here is the working code.

```
            $events = new WP_Query(Array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_type' => 'event',
                'meta_key' => 'event_date',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                'order' => 'ASC'
            ));
            if ($events->have_Posts()){
                while($events->have_posts()){
                    $events->the_post();
                    echo "<p>Event " . get_the_title() . ' ' . get_the_id() . '</p>';

                    $registrations = new WP_Query(Array(
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'post_type' => "registration",
                        'meta_key' => 'boat_type',
                        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'meta_query' => array(
                          array(
                              'key'=> 'event',
                              'compare' => 'LIKE',
                              'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"'
                          )
                        )
                      ));
                      if ($registrations->have_posts()){
                          while ($registrations->have_posts()){
                              $registrations->the_post();
                            echo "<p>---------reg title is: " . get_the_title() . " and id is " . get_the_ID() . "</p>";
                          }
                      }
                }
            }
```

Now displays

```
Event 1
Event 2
---------reg title is: Manual Registration and id is 221
Event 3
Event 4
---------reg title is: Registration and id is 217
---------reg title is: Another Registration and id is 222
Event 5
Event 6
Event 7
Event 8
Event 9
```